# aiohttp module - import error

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

Installed `aiohttp`,

```
pip3 install aiohttp
```

as mentioned [here](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/843)

---

With python3.6,

I see below error:

```
import aiohttp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is because your `pip3` is not in the python3.6 PYTHONPATH. I always think the best way to install Python packages using `pip` is with to run it as a script using the `-m` option.

```
python3.6 -m pip install aiohttp
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue even on Pycharm. After figuring out which interpreter I use I had to explicitly install aiohttp with pip with the python binary under venv/bin.

Comment: I had a similar issue with Pycharm when running `python` for virtual environment from command line. I had to exit the shell, make sure that PyCharm does not activate the virtual environment (`deactivate`), active it by hand and then run `python`.